# Typescript how to iterate with for loop over object

Tags: arrays, typescript, for-loop, for-of-loop

I am writing a Typescript nodejs app where I want to iterate over an incoming sql response but I don't know how to fix the syntax error.

```js
const getTicketPriceBrutto = async (eventID: number): Promise<number> => {
  const rows: [] = await query(
    `SELECT ticketPriceCentBrutto FROM events 
    WHERE eventID = '${eventID.toString()}';`
  );
  let price: number;

  //syntax error...
  // return rows.forEach((element: any) => {
  //   price = element.ticketPriceCentBrutto;
  //   return price;
  // });

  //here is also an syntax error
  for (const iterator of rows) {
    price = iterator.ticketPriceCentBrutto;
  }
  return price;
};
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Do you want the sum? Or is the query supposed to return a single row and you want that value?

Comment: return only a single value. I just use the answers from here and take the 0 entry in the array an return this.

Answer (score 1):

What is the end result you want to get? An array of prices? If yes then use map:

```
const prices = rows.map((item: any) => item.ticketPriceCentBrutto)
```

Also your type for `rows` is syntatically incorrect, it must be an array of something, if you don't know the exact shape of returned objects then use `any[]` instead of just `[]`, this could also be a reason for invalid syntax

Answer (score 1):

In the commented area you have used `forEach` to iterate `rows` array. But forEach doesn't return anything. Here is the correct way to use forEach.

```
const getTicketPriceBrutto = async (eventID: number): Promise<number[]> => {
  const rows: [] = await query(
    `SELECT ticketPriceCentBrutto FROM events 
    WHERE eventID = '${eventID.toString()}';`
  );
  const priceList: number[] = [];

  for (const row of rows) {
    price.push(row.ticketPriceCentBrutto);
  }
  return priceList;
```

};

Another option is using the `map` function provided by javascript.

```
    const getTicketPriceBrutto = async (eventID: number): Promise<number[]> => {
      const rows: [] = await query(
        `SELECT ticketPriceCentBrutto FROM events 
        WHERE eventID = '${eventID.toString()}';`
      ); 
      return rows.map(row => row.ticketPriceCentBrutto);
};
```

Both ways you can return an array of prices from `getTicketPriceBrutto` function

Please check [forEach](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```js
type Row = { ticketPriceCentBrutto: number };

const getTicketPriceBrutto = async (eventID: number): Promise<number | undefined> => {
    const rows: Row[] = await query(
        `SELECT ticketPriceCentBrutto FROM events 
      WHERE eventID = '${eventID}';`
    );

    return rows[0]?.ticketPriceCentBrutto;
};
```